# Choose the target SOA server and corresponding partition | Deploy SOA composite application in Jdeveloper

Tags: weblogic, soa, jdeveloper, composite, bpel

I created a simple SOA application 'Hello' and trying to deploy the same on Jdeveloper but no SOA target server is displayed during deployment. Steps i performed.
1) Installed ADF along with Jdeveloper 11.1.1.3
2) added SOA extension 'soa-jdev-extension 11.1.1.3.zip' by installing it from Help-> Check for updates -> Install from Locale file.
3) Created and saved the SOA application
4) right click the application -> Deploy -> Deploy to application server -> Selected  'Integrated Weblogic Server' to deploy -> Next
5) In next screen ' Choose the target SOA server and corresponding partitions..... ' , no server comes up to select & deploy

DO I need to create a separate domain for soa in weblogic server? OR should i create a partition? Please let me know step by step how can i get it resolved.
Thanks

..........................
Error in my logs:
WARNING: Error reading db partitions for connection name Connection1.Reason : null
Compiling...
Context: selection=SOAHelloBPEL.jpr application=SOA-Application.jws project=SOAHelloBPEL.jpr node=SOAHelloBPEL.jpr
Compilation of project 'SOAHelloBPEL.jpr' finished.
Check 'C:\JDeveloper\mywork\SOA-Application\SOAHelloBPEL\SCA-INF\classes\scac.log' for details.
  ignoring C:\JDeveloper\mywork\SOA-Application\SOAHelloBPEL\BPELProcess1.wsdl; not on source path
  ignoring C:\JDeveloper\mywork\SOA-Application\SOAHelloBPEL\xsd\BPELProcess1.xsd; not on source path
[7:42:57 PM] Compilation complete: 1 errors, 0 warnings.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot deploy to integrated weblogic server in SOA 11g.you have to install standalone server if you want to use 11g.You can use 12c as it comes with integrated SOA and OSB server.